# React-komposer automatically calls multiple times

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-tracker

```
const onPropsChangeTracker = (props, onData) => {
    console.log("**container called**");
    const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('products.list');
    if(subscription.ready()) {
      const productIds = Products.find().fetch().map(product => product._id);
      onData(null, { productIds });
    }
};

const ProductListContainer = composeWithTracker(onPropsChangeTracker)(ProductList);
export default ProductListContainer;
```

This is a code of my react komposer. it automatically calls multiple times. i have used react komposer in other components but there it calls only once but i am still wondering why this one calls itself multiple times while i am using it only once. please do me favor.

no change in props, it receives the empty object each time when it is called

Comment: Is it possible that a parent component is re-rendered, or some product attribute is modified (note that you query for all of them instead of limiting the query to the `_id` field)? What version of Meteor are you using?

Comment: BTW. it will always be called at least twice, when you subscribe and when the subscription is ready.

Comment: No the parent component do not render again n no product attribute is modified but i am limiting the query to ONLY id field

Comment: I am using meteor version 1.4.1.1

Comment: Yup i can understand bcz the ready function of the subscription is reactive. But here it calls thrice or sometimes twice. :(

Comment: Note that the code that you posted does not limit the query to the `_id` field.  The mapping is performed only after the query had already been executed, and the proper way to do this is to supply the [fields option](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find).